# Async operations with substrate library in python

Tags: substrateinterface, python, async-backing

I am curious, does the current python library support Async operations ? For some reason, I am getting an **Aenter** error when calling the substrate in python library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no real async support yet. We are currently working though on a version 2 of the libraries, which will have asyncio support.

Until then you could use threads, but there are some limitations, as discussed here:

https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface/issues/367#issuecomment-1865991334